# Splitting whole numbers into different cells

Tags: python, split, splice

I'm trying to take a number and split it into other cells, so if the number is 12345 then in A1 should have 1, A2 - 2, A3 - 3, A4 - 4, A5 - 5

This is what I have so far though:

```
`    for row in range(0, len(synopData)):
    for cell in range(0, len(synopData[row])):
        colLetter = get_column_letter(cell + 7)
        cellCoord = colLetter + str(row + 2) 
        newSheet[cellCoord] = synopData[row][cell]`
```

So, I can select the column and row where I need to start from but the entire number goes into one cell
Hope I'm making sense
Thanks for your help in advance

thought print would have worked but i dont think i'm doing it right

Comment: What is your expected output? A dictionary like  {"A1": 1, "A2":2, "A3": 3, "A4": 4, "A5": 5}??

Comment: more like a csv file with output, in A1 B1 C1 D1 are the headers, and A2 would have 1,  B2 would have 2, C2 - 3 D2 - 4...

Answer (score 0):

```
num = 123456
separated = list(str(num))
print(separated)  # ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```

is this helps?

Comment: I should mention that the numbers are being pulled from a text file so:   synopData = list(csv.reader(open("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\synopbufrTest\\testFile.TXT")))